# I'm getting this unusual error in my code, Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php

I'm checking if the `$errors` variable is empty, but `foreach()` still complains about an invalid argument:

```
<?php       
    if (empty($errors) === false) {
?>
        <ul>
            <?php
                foreach ($errors as $error) {
                    echo "<li>{$error}</li>";
                }
            ?>
        </ul>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Try using `is_array` along with `count`  instead of `empty` like as `if (is_array($errors) && count($errors) > 0) {`

Comment: @Uchiha make this an answer, this is the correct solution

Comment: @user, I have removed the meta-commentary (complaints about your posts being downvoted) from your question, as it only adds noise. Please refrain from doing that in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`is_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) along with [`count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) instead of [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) like as

```
if (is_array($errors) && count($errors) > 0) {
```

> is_array — Finds whether a variable is an array

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help @user3573987 _(FYI : You can accept or upvote one of these answer if it really helps you.)_

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

So, if $errors is, say, set to an integer value of 2, empty($errors) is going to return true.  However, it isn't an array, hence will be invalid for your foreach loop.

Instead, use is_array().

Also consider, for debugging, using var_dump($errors) and find out exactly what it is at that point.

Comment: It may be, but it looks like it might not be by the time it gets to that foreach loop.  Welcome to the untold joys of dynamic typing.  Use is_array() and prove that it is still an array.  Also consider, for debugging only, using var_dump($errors) and find out exactly what it is at that point.

Comment: Have you run var_dump($errors) on the line directly before you call the foreach?

Comment: yes (comments must be at least 15 characters to post)

Comment: Well, then either you are missing something, or you've turned up a very odd error.  Try posting the output of var_dump along with the precise wording of the error.

Answer (score 0):

The $errors may not be an array, so you must check its type or convert it to array. A simple example:

```
<?php       
    if (empty($errors) === false) {
?>
        <ul>
        <?php
        foreach((array) $errors as $error){
            echo "<li>{$error}</li>";
        }
        ?>
</ul>
<?php
    }

?>
```

Comment: This won't throw an error but it'll surely get within `if` condition